# Alegebra- Function or NOT a function

Tags: relations

if you have a relation with the domains: 0,1,2,3,4 and a range of: 3,1,2,4,2 does this mean it is not a function because there are two outputs of the number 2? Or can it only not be  function if there are two of the same inputs with a different output?

Comment: The second one.

Comment: It's not a function if for some value $x$ you'd have different values of $y$.

Let's say you have a random function $f(x)$ and you plug in $x=1$, if it would show something like $f(1) = 2$ and $f(1)= 3$, it wouldn't be a function.

The reverse is true though, wherein if you have $f(1)=2$ and $f(2)=2$, it would still be a function.

Answer (score 2):

A function can be described as a cartesian product of the domain and the range, so the relation you describe is a function. You are correct when saying that a function can't have an input with two different outputs